# Flutter - ExpansionTile double actions

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Is it possible to configure a `ExpansationTile` to have 2 actions:

- Expand when clicking on the trailing icon
- Going to another screen when clicking anywhere else?

Also, is it possible to omit the trailing icon IF the children of the item doesn't have information to display (eg, sublist is empty)?

Here's what I have ATM:

```
Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Card(
        child: ExpansionTile(
          leading: Image.asset('images'),
          title: Text('Text'),
          subtitle: Text('Text'),
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index2) {
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    onTap: () => print('test'),
                    leading: Image.asset('images'),
                    title: Text('Text'),
                    subtitle: Text('Text'),
                );
              },
              itemCount: list[index].sublist.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
    itemCount: list.length,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  ),
)
```

Comment: are you referring `onTap` to navigate to new route?

Comment: yes, but the ExpansionTile doesnt have onTap, the whole tile on expands the list. I want to be able to expand the list with the trailing icon and navigate clicking anywhere else in the tile

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by adding **IconButton** to the **trailing** part of the **ExpansionTile**.

Here's an example code snippet for the same.

```
ExpansionTile(
   title: const Text('Hello'),
   trailing: IconButton(
      onPressed: () => log('Hello');
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
   ),
   children: const [Text('World')],
),
```